# How to backup memo and task in android

Tags: java, android, task, memo

I have a user requirement to backup memo and Task. I don't have any idea about where is the location actually stored these things in android phone.  Is there any default uri/path is reserved for this?

Can anyone clarify these things in little bit clear.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're question is somewhat unclear. If you could elaborate any it would help out a lot.

In the meantime [check out this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for a good overview of all of the various options you have for storing data in a persistent manner.

Comment: I mean if we need to read Contacts from phone we parse a URI as ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI. So such a way i ask how to access memo and task in android phone

Comment: there is Notes gadget is available in android phone. so where is actually stored. I think this is the think need to backup for memo.